# jQuery popup / overlay effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im really hoping someone can help me out with this project requirement as im new to JS or rather not advanced with it and i only have today to crack this one and no idea how.

Below is an image iwth how the effect needs to be, starts off  from top to bottom, your see how it expands but curved at top and bottom until fully open.

Anyone have any ideas on how i can do this is JS / jQuery (non plugin based) i would be forever greateful if someone could help me on this.

[image: Animation effect overlay]

Thanks a bunch

Comment: You just need to do the shapes?

Comment: Yea the animation effect so it opens up like that until full open then would be totally square. So not on single chapes but an animation effect, so i click a link and a div appears as such and doe sthe effect in the fluid sequance - that image above is just a rough example

Comment: @adeneo: Whooops! Sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without Javascript / jQuery using just CSS3 `border-radius`. However, if you need to fire this up through your existing JS code, then simply wrap the style in a class, and apply that class on some event in your JS code.

Remember that in order to have that elliptical effect you have in your question, the block has to be rectangular and not square, otherwise you will end up in a circle.

***A simple example snippet:***

```css
div {
    margin: 16px;
    height: 10px; width: 240px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
a:focus ~ div {
    height: 120px; width: 240px;   
    border-radius: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click</a>
<div></div>
```

***Snippet using jQuery to fire the effect:***

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#d1").addClass("effect");
});
```

```css
div {
    margin: 16px;
    height: 10px; width: 240px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
div.effect {
    height: 120px; width: 240px;   
    border-radius: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="btn" href="#">Click</a>
<div id="d1"></div>
```

Comment: How would i add the JS so it applys that effect when yoiu click like your did on yours?

Comment: just change the selector `a:focus ~ div` to a class say `div.myclass`. Now apply this class in your code.

Comment: ok thanks, ive added into a demo html but seems to expand out to the right rather than starting at full width, any ideas why that might be and also thanks again!

Comment: ill do a JS Fiddle, sec

Comment: I just updated the answer to add one more snippet using jQuery.

Comment: You forgot the dot before the selector i.e. `.overlay.effect` : http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/8byv9o4o/1/

Comment: Seems on local html file its not starting off full width but ill play with it :) weird as fine on examples here and fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

### Demo on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/ba23c23997d9dfcbc9d9)

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#overlay {
  border-top-left-radius: 1000px 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1000px 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1000px 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1000px 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  -webkit-animation: anim 4s infinite;
  animation: anim 4s infinite;
  height: 800px;
  top: calc(50% - 400px);
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    height: 1px;
    top: calc(50% - 0.5px);
  }
  100% {
    height: 800px;
    top: calc(50% - 400px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    height: 1px;
    top: calc(50% - 0.5px);
  }
  100% {
    height: 800px;
    top: calc(50% - 400px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! couple of things; is it possible to finish the animation off with no radius so sloid corners? and anyway to reverse the animation when closing? really appriciate it mate. thanks oh and ideally want to only action on click of a link etc..